# Do these lead plates have a protective coating? Is it possible to test?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I've just begun teaching chemistry and physics at a local school. We're just getting started on radioactivity and i was looking through the schools supplies when i discovered these soft heavy grey plates used for measuring decay through walls. I've measured the plates' density and IT matches that of lead.
The thing is that i know new sets of these have a coating that prevents lead exposure, i am however, unsure wether these plates have that coating. Sone have a greenish coating I recognize from my own time in school, but the others I am unsure about
[image: picture of plate in question]
L: Coated plate. R: plate in question

Comment: The right one looks like lead without any coating. If you want to be even more sure, check that it is soft enough to be scratched with a wooden toothpick. Check that it reveals a shiny metal surface which turns into the same dull grey in a matter of days.

Comment: Thanks! I've made a scratch test. Will check back in a couple of days

Comment: Agree, they certainly look like plain old lead. Never heard of any coating on lead other than paint.

Comment: Where I work we tend to paint our lead bricks

Comment: Spray it with a clear varnish. (I´d simply wash my hands after using them, but that might be regarded as frivolous in our paranoid century. ;))

Comment: Yes thats what I've been doing, but student safety regulation says that they can't work with pure lead. I've painted them all, so thats hopefully enough